# offscreenpagelimit in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

i want to load previous and next page as by default when PageView has been initialized. But in default implementation the next page is loading when the page is scrolled the next page. is there any way to do that. in android we can simply achieve it by using `offscreenpagelimit` but in flutter I couldn't found any equivalent.

ps: i am showing the image from network in PageView

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand and you aren't sharing your code. Please check the question guidelines to make improvements: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on GitHub about preloading tabs: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31191

Please check their solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
PageView(
  cacheExtents: your_offset_limit_here,
  /// etc
)
```